# How to dry given query code in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have given this code

```
@classes  = Class.includes(:student_classes).where(:employee_id => current_employee.id)
  @students = {}

    unless @classes.blank?
      @classes.each { |class|
        unless class.student_classes.blank?
          class.student_classes.each { |std|
            @students[std.student.id] = std.student.name
          }
        end
      }
    end
```

to fetch @students. Please guide me how to dry this query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose your Class is declared with a ```has_many :student_classes```. Just add a ```has_many :students, through: :student_classes``` and call ```Class.where(employee_id: current_employee.id).students```. For more information, you can (and should) read this article http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association.

Comment: Yes exactly I have this association only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do it :

```
Student
  .joins(student_classes: [:class])
  .where(classes: {employee_id: current_employee.id})
```